# How does the Ring of Spell Storing interact with the Glamour Bard's Mantle of Majesty feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

At level 6 Glamour Bards gain the ability *Mantle of Majesty* which allows them to cast *command* up to 10 times (ability lasts a minute and *command* is cast as a bonus action) without expending a spell slot:

> you take on an unearthly appearance for 1 minute or until your concentration ends (as if you were concentrating on a spell).  During this time you can cast the *command* spell as a bonus action on each of your turns without expending a spell slot.

Does this mean that I could activate the ability (outside of battle) and then store 5 castings of *command* in a *ring of spell storing* for use at a later time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You can't store commands from Mantle of Majesty in a ring of spell storing

The [ring of spell storing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing) can only store spells that were cast using a spell slot. The description seems to imply this by referencing the slot used to cast the spell:

> The level of the slot used to cast the spell determines how much space it uses.

and when casting:

> The spell uses the slot level [...]  of the original caster,

Jeremy Crawford has also stated that this is the case in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/901875657432371200):

> **Armando Doval**‏ @armando_doval
>
> @JeremyECrawford can you cast a spell into a Ring of Spell Storing without expending a slot? Description seems to assume slot is used.
>
> **Jeremy Crawford** @JeremyECrawford
>
> Casting a spell into a ring of spell storing does require a spell slot. #DnD

Despite Jeremy Crawford's tweets [no longer being considered official rulings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140221/), I believe that the tweet and the description taken together are enough support to state that you are not supposed to be able to store a command from Mantle of Majesty into a ring of spell storing.

Answer (score 9):

### You can store commands in the Ring.

The [Ring of Spell Storing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing)'s description states:

> Any creature can cast a spell of 1st through 5th level into the ring by touching the ring as the spell is cast.

The Mantle of Majesty ability states that you're casting the *command* spell itself (as opposed to creating an effect that's equivalent to the command spell), which is compatible with casting the spell into the Ring of Spell Storing.

Note that if you use those spells after Mantle of Majesty ends, you have to use an action to cast *Command*, because you can only cast the spell as a bonus action while the ability is active.

Comment: JC has since tweeted that storing the spells in the ring requires the use of a slot. You may want to update the answer. The tweet can be found [here](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/901875657432371200)